# Object reference for child class

Tags: c#

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass testC = new TestClass();
            testC.AssignRec(10);
            //testC.root - this is null 
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public Childclass root;
        public void Assign(int data)
        {
           AssigRec(this.root,data);
        }
        public void AssignRec(Childclass rootnode, int data)
        {
            if (rootnode == null)
            {
                rootnode = new Childclass(data);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Childclass
    {
        public int data;
        public Childclass(int data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Updated the Child parameter name.
Assigning value for the subclass `ChildClass` inside the `TestClass` but after assigning and if I try to access the Childcalss value it is null. Not sure the reason.

Comment: Where is the code which tries to access it and gets null?

Comment: In `Assign()`, `root` is a *parameter* which hides the member of the same name. You're assigning the new instance to the parameter, which goes out of scope when you exit the method.

Comment: the argument names matching up with the fields irritates my eyes like fak

Comment: @GregK. At the risk of the unclean spirit of Charles Simonyi haunting me for all eternity, I almost wish there were a conventional C# parameter prefix, analagous to `_` for private fields.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I can't stress enough how unbelieavable helpful this convention is. Also Uppercase names for class properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to be careful when we have the exact same name for an argument as a field, because inside the method, the name will refer to the argument unless we specify the field using `this.root`.

So, what the code is doing is assigning the class field `root` ***only if the argument*** `root` ***is*** `null`.

Instead, it seems like you want to do the assignment if the backing field is `null`, in which case you would do something like:

```
    public void AssignRec(Childclass root, int data)
    {
        // Assign the field 'root' to the argument passed to this method unless the argument
        // to this method is 'null', in which case assign a new instance of ChildClass
        this.root = root ?? new ChildClass(data);
    }
```

Although as a consumer of this class I would be a little confused if I called the `Assign` method and passed in some `data`, and nothing happened (which is what would happen if the class field `root` was not `null`).

I would also be confused by a method that takes in both a `ChildClass` ***and*** `data`, since it's not clear what the relationship between these arguments is.

Instead, I would recommend providing two overloads, each with a single argument:

```
public void Assign(int data)
{
    if (this.root == null)
    {
        this.root = new ChildClass(data);
    }
    else
    {
        this.root.data = data;
    }
}

public void Assign(ChildClass root)
{
    this.root = root;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what you want the method to do, then, since your edit makes the desired result even more unclear (since you aren't assigning anything to the class field now). What is the purpose of the method?

Comment: I was trying to understand why passing the this.root in Assign method is not preserving the value which is updated in AssignRec method.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's because you're not assigning anything to `this.root` (you're assigning to the argument name, which doesn't do anything). This answer fixes that issue. But what do you want it to do if the argument `root` is **not** `null`?

Comment: I was trying to understand only the first time assignment.

Comment: Does changing the value in AssignRec gets updated in the root ?. Why should we assign back the value.

Comment: The code in this answer says, assign our class field `this.root` to the argument `root` that was passed into this method, *unless that value is null* in which case assign it a new instance of `ChildClass` using the `data` provided.

Comment: if you could let me know on the changes in the new code would help

Comment: I understand the code that you have provided but i was trying to understand why my code is not preserving the value in the childclass.

Comment: It's as I said in my first sentence, and as you've demonstrated in your updated code. **You are not assigning anything to** `root`. You're only changing the assignment of the **argument** variable, which is thrown away at the end of the method call. Not sure what part you aren't understanding, or why you think that `root` would get changed in your current code.

Comment: If i understand correctly, eventhough we pass this.root into the AssignRec it is treated as local method variable(rootnode/root) and any changes are considered as local.Inorder to get assigned it needs to be assigned back to object root. I was expecting the object reference should automatically update inside the method. But right now i am clear. Thanks for it.

Comment: Yeah, the `root` argument starts out pointing to the `root` field. But when you re-assign it, it now points to a new instance of `ChildClass`. However the `root` **field** is never changed. Think of reference types as pointers to a memory location. If you wanted to do something like `rootArgument.data = someNewData`, however, then you **are** affecting the `root` field data, since `rootArgument` points to the same location as the `root` field.

Comment: The version of my code is little confusing but for many it will be a interesting to find why it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign "new ChildClass(data)" to current instance's root. For that you need to assign the new object to "this.root". Make a change in TestClass like below:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public Childclass root;

        public void Assign(Childclass root, int data)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                //over here
                this.root = new Childclass(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Senthil you have to assign the new ChildClass object to TestClass's data member "root". However in your code you are assigning the new object to the parameter. Either use this.root like in the answer OR you can just change the name of the property to Root (capital R). That will be more clear to read as well.

Comment: @Senthil Renaming the parameter won't help, although it *should* make the nature of the problem more clear to you: You are assigning the new instance to a parameter, which is local to the method. You are still throwing away the new instance. You pass `this.root` into `AssignRec()`, but inside the method the parameter `rootnode` is just a new reference to whatever you passed in. Changing its value will not change the value of `this.root`.

Comment: If you could let me know on the updated code which would be helpful.